# Displaying a comment on an image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449780/displaying-comments-under-an-image) I had an issue where I couldn't display comments on my artist page from friends, I have managed to resolve this issue but now I am struggling to display comments on my images.

All I want to do at the moment is display comments that I have input into the database manually and display them underneath my image.

This is the model for images:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :publishings
  has_many :artists, :through => :publishings
  has_many :comments,:through => :friends
  has_many :comments, :as => :resource, :class_name => "Commentable"
end
```

This is the show.html for images

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<div id="container">
  <p>
    <b>Title:</b>
    <%= @image.title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <b>Filename:</b>
    <%= @image.filename %>
    <%= image_tag @image.filename %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <b>Likes:</b>
    <span id="images_<$=@image.id%>_likes_count"><%= @image.likes %></span>
  </p>
  <div id="comments">
    <h2>Comments</h2> 
    <%= render :partial => "shared/comment", :collection => @image.comments%>
  </div>
</div>

<%= link_to 'Like', like_image_path(@image), :method => :post %> |
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_image_path(@image) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', images_path %>
```

This is the error I am receiving at the moment:

```
> undefined method `first_name' for nil:NilClass

    Extracted source (around line #16):

13: </p>
14: <p>
15:   <b>First name:</b>
16:   <%= @artist.first_name %>
17: </p>
18: 
19: <p>
```

Application Trace

```
app/views/images/show.html.erb:16:in `_app_views_images_show_html_erb___1549892128_70077336775360_0'
app/controllers/images_controller.rb:18:in `show'
```

This is the model for the friends and it displays the correct method:

```
class Friend < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many:friends
  has_many :artists, :through => :publishings

  def display_name
    "#{self.first_name} #{self.second_name}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you put some more effort in formatting your question? Also, `ruby != ruby-on-rails`. Your question is about Ruby on Rails. Please tag appropriately. Finally, I guess it's a typo, so please delete `t_name' for nil:NilClass` from the top of your `Friend` model.

Comment: You should be seeing a stack trace or some other information that identifies which line of code is triggering the exception.  The only line I can see in the code you posted is the body of `display_name`, but I can't see anything that calls that method.  I wonder if there's something missing here, something that we need in order to figure this out.

Comment: My apologies, I have edited above to it displays the application trace.

Answer (score 1):

In yesterday's question, you posted your `ImagesController` but the `show` method never sets the `@artist` variable.

Your stack trace here indicates that the `@artist` variable is nil.

But, since your model indicates that an image can have many artists, your view really should logically change to:

```
<% @image.artists.each do |artist| %>
  <p>
    <b>First name:</b>
    <%= artist.first_name %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: So where do I go from here? I am really new to this and I am really struggling.

Comment: should it be belongs_to :artists rather than has many?



end

Comment: Lawrence. I can't answer that because I don't know what your intention is. The Rails association code reads like prose for a reason. You're saying that an "image has_many :artists". Is that true or not?

Comment: I am sorry, I am really new to this. An image belongs to one artist and many friends can comment on that one image.

Comment: No reason to be sorry, but I think you'll find that you'll get a better understanding of associations by thoroughly reading the ActiveRecord associations documentation http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Thank you, I have set it to has_one :artist, :though => :publishings but I am having no luck at all.

Comment: I'm going to leave this to you. I think I answered your original question, but I think you'll gain a better understanding by thoroughly understanding the ActiveRecord documentation. ActiveRecord is fundamental to the great majority of Rails apps and once you master that you'll be well on your way. It's probably best to learn it in a more structured way by reading the documentation.